# Is there a Python code for generating code sequence

Tags: python

i am looking for a python code for the following case. I have a main system with three subsystems with each some sub-subsystems.

Is there a code to generate the sequence given a starting number (prefix), number of subsystems, and number of sub-subsystems under the subsystem?

Example:

```
Bike 
    Frame
         Paint
    Wheels
         Tires
         Hub
         Tube
         Rim
    Steering wheel
```

The code should generate:

```
Level 1  Level2   Level3
1      |        |
       |   1.1  |
                | 1.1.1
       |   1.2  |
                | 1.2.1
                | 1.2.2
                | 1.2.3
                | 1.2.4
       |   1.3  |

Thank you in advance!
```

**I already came up with the following code: **

```
def generate_codes(prefix, level, max_level):
  if level > max_level:
    return

  for i in range(10):
    code = "{}-{}".format(prefix, i)
    print(code)
    generate_codes(code, level + 1, max_level)

generate_codes("1", 1, 3)
```

This code does not generate the link between level 2 and level 3. I need a way to also put in the relationship between level 2 and 3.

Comment: Your code doesn't take in account the input. Read the input line by line and the number of indentation spaces will tell you the depth level you are. Then compare the current element depth with the previous element depth and you know if you have a child of the previous element, a sibling or if you have a new parent. Give it a try. For example you can start just by reproducing the initial tree but appending the depth level to each element. After that, try appending an index that increases for each sibling and resets back to 0 for a child or a parent.

Comment: What actually *is* your input?

Comment: For that matter, what is your intended output? A dictionary or other data structure? Or a file/string formatted exactly as shown?

Answer (score 0):

I'll not solve your problem, but give you some code you can use to build your solution

We start with the data, you can read it from a file, but to simply things I'll hardcode it into a string

```
data = """Bike 
    Frame
         Paint
    Wheels
         Tires
         Hub
         Tube
         Rim
    Steering wheel"""

# split the data line by line into a list
data = data.split('\n')
```

The first thing is getting the depth of each element.
You can do this by substracting the length of the unmodified line with the length of the line after removing the indentation spaces.

```
# get the depth of each line
for i in range(len(data)):
    line = data[i]
    line_stripped = line.lstrip()
    
    depth = len(line) - len(line_stripped)
    print(depth)

0 Bike
4     Frame
9          Paint
4     Wheels
9          Tires
9          Hub
9          Tube
9          Rim
4     Steering wheel
```

Now check the relationship of the current element with the previous.

Since you compare with previous elements you have to consider special cases like the root. Comparing if the current depth is greater lower or equal than the previous element will give you their relationship.

```
for i in range(0, len(data)):
    if i == 0:
         print(f"{data[i]} \t Root")
         continue
         
    line = data[i]
    line_stripped = line.lstrip()
    
    depth = len(line) - len(line_stripped)
    depth_prev = len(data[i-1]) - len(data[i-1].lstrip())

    if depth > depth_prev:
        relationship = "child"
    elif depth < depth_prev:
        relationship = "New Parent"
    else:
        relationship = "sibling"
        
    print(f"{data[i]} \t {relationship}")


Bike                     Root
    Frame                child
         Paint           child
    Wheels               New Parent
         Tires           child
         Hub             sibling
         Tube            sibling
         Rim             sibling
    Steering wheel       New Parent
```

Now with this skeleton you should be able to keep track of the versions, and increase their values depending on the depth level and the relationships.

You can keep the version as a list of elements, like this

```
version 1.2.3  ->  [1, 2, 3]
```

So you can easily access an element to increase it, or you can add subversions by appending an element to the list

```
[1, 2, 3].append(1)  -> [1, 2, 3, 1]  -> version 1.2.3.1
```

Think about what you have to to if you find a child. what you have to do if you find a sibling and what you have to do if you find a new parent.

Good luck

Answer (score -1):

Since you did not specify your data input shape, Code below assume it is stored in `yaml` format.

```py
import yaml
import io

raw_data = io.StringIO("""
- name: bike
  children:
    - name: frame
      children:
        - name: paint
    - name: wheels
      children:
        - name: tiers
        - name: hub
        - name: tube
        - name: rim
    - name: steering_wheel
""")


def _traverse(item, level):
    print(level)
    if not item.get("children"):
        return
  
    for i, child in enumerate(item.get("children")):
        _traverse(child, level=f"{level}.{i+1}")

def traverse(items):
    for i, item in enumerate(items):
        _traverse(item, f"{i+1}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
  traverse(yaml.safe_load(raw_data))
```

which should print

```
1
1.1
1.1.1
1.2
1.2.1
1.2.2
1.2.3
1.2.4
1.3
```

You can also modify print statement to say print name and number for example re-define `_traverse` to be

```py
def _traverse(item, level):
    print(f"{level} -> {item.get('name')}")
    if not item.get("children"):
        return
  
    for i, child in enumerate(item.get("children")):
        _traverse(child, level=f"{level}.{i+1}")
```

running should print

```
1 -> bike
1.1 -> frame
1.1.1 -> paint
1.2 -> wheels
1.2.1 -> tiers
1.2.2 -> hub
1.2.3 -> tube
1.2.4 -> rim
1.3 -> steering_wheel
```